# How to mark word or sentence in single brackets {,(,[,» using regular expression in regex101 tool php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to mark word or sentence with single bracket, this bracket may  be place in left or right and middle of word or sentence.

Other words or sentence in regex101 tool should not be disturb
Example below https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/14

[image]

Comment: Not getting you point.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more, what exactly your matching conditions are?

Comment: I did share the regex101 tool,
https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/15

In this tool this words are mentions
[weather          
weather]           
[weather is good   
weather is good] 
I want mark these words other below mark words should not unmark

Comment: @RaheelAslam Do one thing update your post with input strings and  expected matches, also add which should not be matched

Comment: Did you see the link? simple i want this one words as mark example

    "(weather" ,"weather)", "we(ather" ,"weathe)r"

Comment: @Sebastian Proske
in this example these words should not be match.
    
    (Weather) is good.    // not need to mark this beacuase this word correct word
    
    i want tops words match below.   
    https://regex101.com/r/9PCacf/16

Comment: I already told you that regex cannot check if a word is a real English, French, German, etc. word, you should check each match against a spelling dictionary.

Comment: @Wiktor I think the OP is only concerned with the symbols and their placement relative to each word.

Comment: @mickmackusa: Worse, OP calls sequences of words a "word". That makes this question unclear, at least to me.

Comment: @Wiktor 
I am not checking the spelling. just  i am only match/mark words that's wrapped with single brackets and do not mark other double brackets wrapped with example below.
Example :
(weather            //// should be mark
weather)           //// should be mark
wea(ther          // should be mark
weath)er         //    should be mark
(weather is good)     / should not mark
(weather)      / should not mark
same case in other brackets  [.{,»   .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (if you're fine with simply finding faulty lines)

```
^(?:                     # Start of line and alternation group
.*[[{(«][^\]})»\n]*      # un-closed
|
[^[{(«\n]*[\]})»].*      # never opened
|
.*\w[[{(«].*             # opened mid-word
|
.*[\]})»]\w.*            # closed mid-word
)$                       # End of line and alternation group
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SqCR1y/6).

**Edit:**

To tests the different bracket types pairwise, use

```
^(?:\([^)\n]*|[^(\n]*\).*|\[[^]\n]*|[^[\n]*\].*|{[^}\n]*|[^{‌​\n]*}.*|«[^»\n]*|[^«‌​\n]*».*|.*\w[[{(«].*‌​|.*[\]})»]\w.*)$
```

Harder to read (longer) but may be more accurate for you.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SqCR1y/11).

Comment: When i use this regex in 
preg_match("/.*[[{(«][^\]})»]*($|\s*\/\/) |^[^[{(«]*[\]})»].*$|.*\w[[{(«].*|.*[\]})»]\w.*/", $fireabse_text)
it matches  some words some does not. please

Comment: This is what my latest edit looks like w/o spaces and comments `^(?:.*[[{(«][^\]})»\n]*|[^[{(«\n]*[\]})»].*|.*\w[[{(«].*|.*[\]})»]\w.*)$` - [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SqCR1y/7).

Comment: @ClasG What are those `\n`'s doing in there?  Shouldn't you be stripping out the comments before developing your pattern to match the samples??  The comments are a guide.

Comment: @mickmackusa The `\n` is there to not get multi line matches. And... "comments"? Yeah, I guess you could see them as that. But why strip them out if it isn't necessary?

Comment: @ClasG
When i type this scenario above updated link 
https://regex101.com/r/SqCR1y/7

this regex does not mark.

Example:
(weather [is fine]

Comment: Since your examples didn't have any cases like that (mixed brackets) I made a compromise and made one regex to handle them all. If you need to mix them you'll basically have to make one regex for each case, and that would make it very complicated (or rather long and difficult to read).

Comment: This may do it for you though: `^(?:\([^)\n]*|[^(\n]*\).*|\[[^]\n]*|[^[\n]*\].*|{[^}\n]*|[^{\n]*}.*|«[^»\n]*|[^«\n]*».*|.*\w[[{(«].*|.*[\]})»]\w.*)$`. [Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SqCR1y/11). It tests the brackets pairwise.

Comment: Please see  this one, When i add this regex in preg_match function it matches all cases but except one it does not match 
this case  

«weather is fine»

Comment: if((preg_match("/^(?:.*[[{(«][^\]})»\n]*|[^[{(«\n]*[\]})»].*|.*\w[[{(«].*|.*[\]})»]\w.*)$/", $fireabse_text)){}else{}

Comment: <?php 
$fireabse_text = '«countary is a citey»';
            if (preg_match("/^(?:\([^)\n]*|[^(\n]*\).*|\[[^]\n]*|[^[\n]*\].*|{[^}\n]*|[^{\n]*}.*|«[^»\n]*|[^«\n]*».*|.*\w[[{(«].*|.*[\]})»]\w.*)$/i", $fireabse_text)) {
                echo " does  not match";
            }else{
                echo "match";
            }
?>

Comment: @ClasG 
Last  any bracket this one « is not  handling in preg_match function please see code.

Comment: First of all - the regex in your code example doesn't match mine! It's missing escapes for several brackets. Secondly - `«countary is a citey»` is correctly bracketed, so it **shouldn't match** (return "does not match"), which both your "faulty" regex, and mine, doesn't. [Check this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/23n9-4ams).

Comment: I have found the solution. thanks
This issue was due to regex pattern i have define regex pattern with "mxu" 
example :
preg_match("/^(?:\([^)\n]*|[^(\n]*\).*|\[[^]\n]*|[^[\n]*\].*|{[^}\n]*|[^{\n]*}.*|«[^»\n]*|[^«\n]*».*|.*\w[[{(«].*|.*[\]})»]\w.*)$/mxu", $fireabse_text))
now this example is working fine.